# Ansible - rsyslog installation and configuration

Tags: ubuntu, automation, ansible, rsyslog, centos8

I am new to ansible, and trying to install rsyslog on remote hosts and configure them as clients and to forward events to the rsyslog server as described below:

- If rsyslog is already installed:

  - don't make any changes.
  - If rsyslog is running

    - print the forwarding addresses found. (Currently I copy the script "listIP.py" to the remote host, run it and then delete it. This step is working as expected)
  - else

    - replace the the config file with my predefined rsyslog.conf (this step also works as expected)
- else

  - install rsyslog (working fine)
  - replace config file
  - restart service

when the remote host doesn't have rsyslog installed, I get the error: "while evaluating conditional (ansible_facts.services["rsyslog.service"].state != "running"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rsyslog.service' "

I think it might be because the rsyslog.service.state was populated at the very beginning (before the installation) and therefore the failure.

Other possible option is that after the installing rsyslog, the service is inactive (dead).

Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Please the the playbook below-

```
---

- hosts: Linux_Servers
  become: yes
  gather_facts: True
  debugger: "on_failed"

  handlers:

    - name: Replace rsyslog config file
      copy:
        src: /home/controller/Desktop/rsyslog.conf
        dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
        force: yes
      listen: "Replace config file"
    - name: verify rsyslog running
      service:
        name: rsyslog
        state: started
      listen: "Replace config file"

  tasks:

    - name: Gathering services state...
      service_facts:

    - name: do facts module to get latest information
      setup:
        filter:
          - 'rsyslog'

    - name: If Rsyslog installed, print rsyslog current status. else - move to OS based installation.
      debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services["rsyslog.service"]

    - name: OS check
      debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"
      register: distro

    - name: The detected OS is CentOS. Installing rsyslog...
      yum:
        name: rsyslog
      register: installedSuccess
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'CentOS'

    - name: The detected OS is Ubuntu. Installing rsyslog...
      apt:
        name: rsyslog
      register: installedSuccess
      when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Ubuntu"

    - name: After success installation, replace config file.
      copy:
        src: /home/controller/Desktop/rsyslog.conf
        dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
        force: yes
      when: installedSuccess

# update service data?

    - name: Rsyslog is installed but not running. restarts service now...
      service:
        name: rsyslog
        state: started
      when: ansible_facts.services["rsyslog.service"].state != "running"

    - name: Rsyslog is installed and running. Copying script to find forwrding address...
      copy: src=/home/controller/Desktop/listIP.py dest=listIP.py
      when: ansible_facts.services["rsyslog.service"].state == "running"

    - name: search rsyslog_conf for rsyslog server IP addresses
      command: python listIP.py
      register: IPaddress
      when: ansible_facts.services["rsyslog.service"].state == "running"

    - name: Found forwarding address-
      debug: msg="{{ IPaddress.stdout }}"

    - name: Clean Script From Remote Host
      file:
        state: absent
        path: "listIP.py"
      when: IPaddress

    - name: No forwarding address found. Replace conf file...
      copy:
        src: /home/controller/Desktop/rsyslog.conf
```

Comment: You need to run the install step before checking the service status

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is 8 months late but I figured I would put in my solution here in case anyone else comes across this.

The primary issue here is that Ansible only collects facts at the beginning of a play and does not update the fact vars mid-play, so when you are checking for the service's state after installation via checking the facts, you're checking against the initial state.

There are a few ways around this, but the easiest and most straight forward is to just call the Ansible setup module (ansible.builtin.setup) again, filtering for the fact you want. Something like that would look like this:

```
- name: SELinux - Force ansible to regather facts
  setup: filter='rsyslog'
```

I have not tested this exactly but the principle is sound; calling setup like above re-invokes the setup module which collects the facts at the beginning. **I do not believe this updates the ansible_facts variable** for that you would most likely have to re-assign the variable via the set_fact module, or call the setup module with different options.